# Angular JS [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs

error showing like this, i dont know what wrong with the syntax, I have try many way to correct it. it just showing injector:unpr. can Any body help may problem?

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=intervalProvider%20%3C-%20interval%20%3C-%20chatList
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/.../public/assets/js/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost/.../public/assets/js/angular.min.js:40:239
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost/.../public/assets/js/angular.min.js:38:225)
    at http://localhost/.../public/assets/js/angular.min.js:40:313
    at d (http://localhost/sahra2/public/assets/js/angular.min.js:38:225)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost/.../public/assets/js/angular.min.js:38:495)
    at $get.Q.instance (http://localhost/../public/assets/js/angular.min.js:80:122)
    at N (http://localhost/.../public/assets/js/angular.min.js:61:181)
    at g (http://localhost/.../public/assets/js/angular.min.js:54:386)
```

app.js

```
var App = angular.module('App',['luegg.directives'], function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('!}');
});
App.controller('sendMails', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.submit=function(){
        alert($scope.fromMail);
        if($scope.fromMail){
            var mailData={

                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'http://localhost/.../public/auth/mail',
                header  :{
                    'Content-Type'  : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data    :{
                    secureKey   : 'tie44jfuho9piya7219',
                    fromMail    : $scope.fromMail,
                    mailto      : $scope.mailto,
                    subject     : $scope.subject,
                    message     : $scope.message
                }
            }
            $http(mailData)
                .success(function(response){
                    alert(response.status);
                })
                .error(function(){
                    alert('error');
                });
        }
    }
});
var app2 = angular.module('App');
app2.controller('chatList', function($scope, $http, interval){
    interval(function(){
        $http.get('localhost/.../public/auth/chat')
            .success(function(response){
                $scope.chats = response;
            });
    },1000);
});
```

and app.php

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="sendMails">
                    <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" ng-model="fromMail" name="fromMail" ng-init="fromMail='{{ Auth::user()->userID}}'" />
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mailto" name="emailto" placeholder="Email to:"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <textarea ng-model="message" placeholder="Message" style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer clearfix">
                        <button class="pull-right btn btn-default" type="submit" id="sendEmail">Send <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
<div class="box-body chat" id="chat-box" ng-controller="chatList">
                        <!-- chat item -->
                        <div class="item" ng-repeat="x in chats">
                            <img src="dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg" alt="user image" class="online"/>
                            <p class="message">
                                <a href="#" class="name">
                                    <small class="text-muted pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2:15</small>
                                    {$ x.name !}
                                </a>
                                I would like to meet you to discuss the latest news about
                                the arrival of the new theme. They say it is going to be one the
                                best themes on the market
                            </p>

                        </div><!-- /.item -->
                        <!-- chat item -->

                    </div><!-- /.chat -->
```

what wrong , error showing [$injector:unpr]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide `$` injecting `interval`

try like this

```
function($scope, $http, $interval){
    $interval(function(){
      // do stuff
    },1000);

}
```